# Undecidability of emptiness of LBA

Tags: turing-machines, linear-bounded-automata

How is the emptiness of Linear Bound Automata (LBA) i.e $L = \{B \mid L(B) = \emptyset \}$ is undecidable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a Turing machine $M$, we can construct an LBA $B$ which on input of length $n$ checks whether $M$ halts on the empty input within $n$ space. Therefore $L(B)$ is empty iff $M$ doesn't halt.

Comment: can you kindly explain "whether  halts on the empty input within  space" part?

Comment: The LBA can simulate the Turing machine on it’s available space, which is $n$ cells. If the Turing machine tries to use more space, it can just abort.

Comment: So... if it does abort, then it means that this particular input needs more space? I'm trying to see where the contradiction happens.

Comment: If it aborts on an input in length $n$, then $M$ uses more than $n$ space.